# Laravel with Node.js: "Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment"

Tags: node.js, laravel, runtime-error, node-sass

So I did not have installed Node before, just standard Laravel. Today I installed Node.js 8 and now one of my older projects tells me the following in the console:

```
app.js:66591 Uncaught Error: Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Error: Missing binding /node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-57/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Node.js 8.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 6.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass --force` to build the binding for your current environment.
```

Unfortunately, 'npm rebuild node-sass --force' doesn't change anything. I tried to install either Node 6 or 8, but I cannot get rid of the error (site is still working anyway, is Laravel using Node only for npm?).

So what's the solution for this?

Comment: Try a clean install: `rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install` (note that node 8 will require `npm cache clean --force`)

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `node_modules` directory and running `npm install` again? This will force your project to reinstall all the node packages, although it won't work if the `node-sass` package was installed globally. And just for your info: Laravel uses node only for building assets (compiling your SASS to CSS in this case).

Comment: @Brian I tried     rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean --force && npm install, but I still get the error.

Comment: @Kryten So what should I do if it was installed globally?

Comment: Try `npm -g rebuild node-sass`, if that doesn't work uninstall it globally (`npm -g uninstall node-sass && npm -g install node-sass`). If it's use in an npm script it does not need to be installed globally though.

Comment: So I tried to uninstall, but I get the error that I don't have the permissions to do that, even though I used sudo.     checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

Comment: Yikes. You shouldn't be installing with `sudo`. Make sure your directory permissions are correct and install everything correctly without `sudo`

Comment: Alright, so it wasn't enough that my account had permission, 'everyone' needed permission for this directory to write. Now everything is back to normal, thank you very much.